# Regular Expression "[ ]" was not closed but still work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a forward function in Spring, which is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
public String redirect() {
    return "forward:/";
}
```

1. What I confused is, why the "[" on left of "path" is not closed, but still worked? Cannot understand this.
2. Looks like it only matched `www.sample.com/aaa` but will not match `www.sample.com/aaa/bbb/`, how should I modify?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `"/**"` instead of a regular expression here.